# Reading all Files in the Directory and Attaching them Using R,

Tags: r, directory, rbind

I want to read all of the files in the directory and attach them. I wrote **Code 1** and it didn't worked properly. I put only two files in the directory (to test) and I changed **Code 1** to **Code 2** which worked properly. I don't understand why **Code 1** is not working.

```
library(data.table)

#### Code 1
for (file in list.files()){

   # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
   if (!exists("dataset")){
     dataset <- fread(file, header=TRUE, sep=",")
    }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
   if (exists("dataset")){
     temp_dataset <-fread(file, header=TRUE, sep=",")
     **dataset**<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
     rm(temp_dataset)
   }
}


#### Code 2
for (file in list.files()){

   # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
   if (!exists("dataset")){
     dataset <- fread(file, header=TRUE, sep=",")
    }

  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
   if (exists("dataset")){
     temp_dataset <-fread(file, header=TRUE, sep=",")
     **dataset2**<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
     rm(temp_dataset)
   }
}
```

Comment: `dataset <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(), fread))`

Comment: @Roland, Sure that works, but I am trying to import one by one to do some cleaning before attaching them. I am also curious to find why the codes end up with different results (assuming there are only two files).

Comment: Using (repeated) `rbind` like your code does is very inefficient (read "slow"). Do your cleaning in the `lapply` loop.

Comment: @Roland, yes it was more efficient. To understand better, I use `rbind` many times and your code use it once, is that the difference in efficiency?

Comment: Not only. Using `rbind` once would be `do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(), fread))`. `rbindlist` is further optimized.